# How to add NetworkManager component in unity 2019

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

After a lot of tutorials of Unet, I'm trying to add networkManager component to an empty object.

But I couldn't find it? Is it removed from this version?

Hope you give me some advice because I'm looking to publish my game.

I tried a lot of tutorials also asked a lot of questions in Unity forum 
but the component doesn't shown.

Answer (score 3):

In 2019 it's Windows>Package Manager>"Multiplayer HLAPI" package. I works but it's very slowly being discontinued.
You can also switch to an open-source community replacement like [github.com/vis2k/Mirror](https://github.com/vis2k/Mirror) ([asset store release](https://assetstore.unity.com/?q=vis2k%20mirror)).